# What is the mean of "On Page SEO"?

Tags: xhtml, seo, accessibility, semantic-markup

What is the mean of "On Page SEO"? Is it related to mark-up , accessibility and semantics?

Edit:

Does "On Page SEO" requires input from XHTML Coder?
Is it a job of developer?

Comment: simply visit the SEO wiki... for more information about "On Page SEO" [http://en.seowiki.info/onpage_seo](http://en.seowiki.info/onpage_seo)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a specific programming probelm as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**incrediman** answered almost all parts of your question. Here are some of my thoughts which I believe is helpful to you.

As you saied, usually we tend to split SEO into two parts, On site and off site.

First let talk a little bit about off site SEO. Since Google and other search engines put special weight on links, both internal and external, people usual try to build in-bound links from other relevant sites. This is basically called OFF SITE SEO.

Then On-site SEO. It is arguably the most important part of SEO, and we can boil it down to two parts too, one is content related, another is code related.

Code related on site SEO refers to write semantic code, build user-friendly web site structure, remov dead links , design sound internal links(contrary to off-site SEO) and so on.

Regarding to content related SEO, it usually marketers' job to take care of. There is a saying that **content is the king**, and that means good title, mata description, keywords and so forth are extremely important to consider when you do SEO.

Plus, IMHO, On-site SEO and On-Page SEO are basically the same except on-site SEO inclines to  build whole site structure, especially internal links between different pages on the site.

Comment: really helpful for me. so i can only provide code level On-site SEO. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: You might be inclined to think that 'on-site seo' is different from 'on-page seo'. But on-page and on-site are referring to from the search engine's perspective, and the url structure is part of the page.

Answer (score 8):

I will define (briefly) SEO, and then break it up into On-Page (a synonym for on-site) SEO and Off-Site SEO:

**SEO**
SEO is the practice of optimizing a website's search engine rankings (or appearance). For example you could perform SEO by doing things which boost your site's position in Google searches.

**Off-Site SEO**
Off-site SEO is where you perform actions completely off of your site that optimize your search engine rankings. For example if you have three sites A, B, and C, you can perform Off-Site SEO on A by linking to it from B and C.

**On-Site (On-Page) SEO**
This refers to SEO you perform for your site by only modifying things *on your own site*. For example:

- Meta Tags
- Providing an XML sitemap
- Ensuring that your internal links all work
- Removing excessive spam from your forums

---

Edit - To answer your question directly: You are performing on-page SEO **if and only if** you are performing a modification on your site that is optimizing your website for search engines.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation. so On-site and on-page SEO are same? for content i just get content from client and i use as it is.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: Yes, they are exactly the same. For example, see this page http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/07/08/google-onsite-seo/ (a top result in google for `on page seo`). The url says onsite-seo, and the title says On-page Seo; they are interchangeable.

Comment: Yes. SEO on the site involves several different actions:  
* Improving page markup to display relevant page content in a clutter free manner  
* Making site content accessible (implying that site content should be easily and clearly accessible with JS and CSS disabled)  
* Flash content, JS enhanced content (like scrolling images, on page JS tabs) should have HTML fall-back  
* Images should have alternative text  
* Links on the site should be to legit content  

The exact actions for SEO are bit of a gray area by these are some simple and objective guidelines that you can follow.

Comment: I guess the main things you can do for Off-Site SEO are (1) to ensure that other related sites who might be interested in linking to you know about your site, and (2) buying links to your site in the form of advertisements. P.s. in the first sentence you mean synonym, not acronym.

Answer (score 3):

On Page Optimization is any form of SEO that focuses solely on the domain and not anything external to it (such as how other sites link to it). These graphics illustrate it best:

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/4-graphics-to-help-illustrate-onpage-optimization

Answer (score 2):

the answers here are spot on

when i need to explain the difference to clients, i put it this way:

"on-page seo is what i can do as a programmer with the code of your website to make it rank well on google. off-page seo is more about you getting your website name-dropped on other websites"

of course, that is a very basic explanation designed for non-tech savvy people, but its a start

--LM

---

if you wanted ***specific*** examples of on-page seo, you could follow this list:

[image]

reference: [Bare Minimum On-Page SEO](http://pm4web.blogspot.com/2008/08/bare-minimum-on-page-seo.html)

Answer (score 1):

On Page Optimization is the way through which website designed according to Google webmaster guidelines and rules.

Answer (score 0):

from [link](http://www.seoco.co.uk/seo-articles/on-page-seo-basics.html)

> On page SEO or search engine
>   optimisation is making sure that your
>   website is as search engine friendly
>   as possible. If your website is not
>   optimised then you have less chance of
>   getting good results in the search
>   engines

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of it myself but according to [this page](http://www.discountclick.com/help/seo/on_page.asp)

> "On Page" SEO simply refers to the
>   text and content on your web site
>   pages. Basically editing your page and
>   content so the Search Engine can find
>   your webpage when a surfer is
>   searching for your web sites
>   particular topic.

Answer (score 0):

On-page optimization is the first half operation to optimize website(seo). In which all onsite modification, new development needs to be done to make your website/webpages more readable, friendly to the crawler & User.

And yes don't think like that you have to be hard-coded professional developer to execute.
Normal HTML knowledge is much enough.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, On page SEO deals with the structure and content of the website like meta tile, descriptions,keywords, url navigations, proper links within the website, etc.

Comment: Meta Keywords are *not* used for SEO anymore.

Answer (score 0):

On-Page SEO is something that is inside your code of website which helps the search engines to crawl your website efficiently and determine which content to show in search results.

There are various factors for which search engines prefer a On-Page optimized website. However there are different techniques to achieve best On-Page SEO practices.

Check this: https://www.stackmantle.com/post/on-page-seo

Its is explained in details for basic yet strong On-Page SEO

alternatively there are more factors once On-Page SEO is done.

You may refer: https://www.stackmantle.com/category/seo